# Custom Redirect page is not working

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I have the Custom Error  `<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx"/>`.

Its totally not working, tried `<deployment retail="false"/>` No result.

**Application in Azure App service, so No role of IIS here. Please help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all Process But non of then worked, Finally i tried with Application_Error() In Global.asax & it worked. But till now unable to get why Non of the process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you could leverage `customErrors` to configure your error pages based on the error code (e.g. 404,403,500,etc.) as follows:

```html
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/NotFound.aspx"/>
    </customError>
</system.web>
```

Also, you could leverage `httpErrors` for IIS 7+ as follows:

```html
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/NotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Moreover, you could leverage `Application_Error` and `Application_EndRequest` events, Custom HttpModule to capture the errors. Details you could refer to this [tutorial](https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging).

Comment: I tried all process but didn't help me anyway. so I finally followed the process of the Global file.